# How to pass values from mustache to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mustache

WHen generating HTML, I can easily fetch properties from JSON objects that I need by simply calling

```
{{cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name}}
```

then the html would include "google", "amazon" or any other objects asked.

however, when I try to do

```
<script>
  var company = cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name
</script>
```

company is assigned `null`.

so how do I go about setting the company value to a string obtainable by html?

Here is the overall page I am trying to generate:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      var address = "lamar ";
      //address = "austin, tx";
      //var address ={{cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name}}
      //address +=" Company, ";
      address += locJson[jobLocID].location_name;
      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 11,
          center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        if (geocoder) {
          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                    { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                    });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map, 
                    title:address
                }); 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });

              } else {
                alert("No results found");
              }
            } else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
     <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:200px;"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: `{{cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name}}` does not look like plain HTML, but rather like some template language like [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Can you describe more of your setup? How do you generate HTML?

Comment: I reworded your question to include mustache, because I'm pretty sure that you are using mustache or handlebars or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make sense to put the company name into HTML and then, in your JS, parse it from HTML. Example:

```
<script>
  // …
  var address = document.getElementyById('company-name');
  // …
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:200px;">
   This should be a map showing the location of <span id="company-name">{{cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name}}</span>.
 </div>
</body>
```

That way, you also get a nice fallback for when the map fails to load.